# Connect new footings to old footings

Tags: concrete, footings

I have a 7 foot section of an addition that has no footing. It is a square addition, so 3 walls on the back of the house. It is about 13 x 12. One of the side walls is missing about 7' of footing and is just blocks in dirt.

I want to go ahead and pour the right footing for it. Can I just pour it right next to the existing footing or do I need to some how join the footings with rebar?

I'm in Raleigh, NC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in with some rebar dowels to be sure that there won't be any differential settlement of the foundations.

You might need to underpin the missing foundation to properly support the blocks.